# Can I change the cname of my domain to any other domain I want?

Tags: dns

I own a domain name can i change it's CNAME to make it point to any other domain that I don't own?

Example: I own a domain name (balh.com)

can I make it an alias for google.com and yahoo.com?

means when I enter (balh.com) in the web browser it shows the google.com webpage with the address (blah.com)?

Answer (score 1):

While you could, all it would achieve would be to return the wrong ip address for your site. Browsers would then ask the incorrect ip address to serve a site for your domain name.

How google or yahoo could choose to deal with this might vary. It could be as simple as displaying an error message, or at worse it could blacklist your domain for some reason.

It certainly wouldn't garner any benefit to your site in terms of search engine ranking.

Comment: I've a hosting space at myhost.freehosting.com an a free domain at mydomain.co.cc I want to change the cname of the mydomain.co.cc to myhost.freehosting.com will that work or they must provide facilities to do that, thank you

Comment: Which configurations should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will only work if the remote site is configured to serve the correct content for your hostname.
Therefore, for example, it won't work with shared virtual hosts.

You can try it without changing DNS by editing your HOSTS file.

Comment: I've a hosting space at myhost.freehosting.com an a free domain at mydomain.co.cc I want to change the cname of the mydomain.co.cc to myhost.freehosting.com will that work or they must provide facilities to do that, thank you

Comment: You must configure the host to respond to the hostname.

Comment: so they must give me the permission to do that?

Comment: Which configuration should I do?

Comment: You need to configure the hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't change CNAME for domain, because can *CNAME exist only for hosts inside domain*
2. Yes, you **can** CNAME hostname in your domain to **any other hostname from any domain**. Sense of such operation is beside the scope of question, but it can exist